# How to link a table when something doesn't exist

Tags: sql, t-sql, join

I have 2 tables I want to look at, A holds some employees (call it 50), B holds some times they clock in. They have a unique ref of employee ref to link the 2 tables. However, I want to know how I can see those that have no clock in today. If I join on on empref I 'only' get those with a clock today. Ideally I'd like to get a time for those today, and something for those who didn't clock today.
I also have a 3 table C, which looks up job descriptions.

How do I return the full employee list, but include those who haven't clocked today?

> ```
> `SELECT emp.empref
>   ,emp.surname
>   ,emp.forenames
>   ,j.jobpostname
>   ,ct.inactual
> FROM empdetails emp
> INNER JOIN jobposts j ON emp.jobpostref = j.jobpostref
> LEFT JOIN clockingtimes ct ON emp.empref = ct.empref
> WHERE emp.deptref = 4
>   AND ct.clockdate = '2023-05-02 00:00:00.000'`
> ```

emp table like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/otdH4.png)

clockingtimes table like:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bsqnL.png)

Where employee 2 hasnt clocked on the day, I would like to show as such all 3 employees, 2 with times 1 without. The time is in seconds of the day, 24000 seconds would be about 06:40 in the day.

Comment: Sample data and expected results would help

Comment: Move the `AND ct.clockdate...` into the `ON` in the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: samples and expected added, adding the ct.clockdate on the left, created an error

Comment: I don't see any mention of an error in your post. You need `LEFT JOIN clockingtimes ct ON emp.empref = ct.empref AND ct.clockdate = '2023-05-02 00:00:00.000'`

Comment: When I select * from empdetails there are 45 employees
When I use the above query, only 34 of these have clocked on that day. But I'd like the output to show 45 employyes, 34 with times, 11 without.
Same with changing the left join, sitll only pulls those with times.

Comment: Then perhaps you need a `LEFT JOIN jobposts` also. Left-joins do not remove rows, so you need to find out which caluse is doing that. Unless you can givce a [mcve] (maybe using https://dbfiddle.uk) that shows the issue, we cannot help further.